# Restoring the secondary server in log shipping

Tags: sql, recovery, log-shipping

I am currently setting up log shipping for a client and have a question.

The process of setting up the log shipping is pretty straight forward but I do not see much information about failing over to that secondary server event of DR.

The secondary database is in Standby (Recovering). Do I simply restore the back up again?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google or Bing to search the phrase "Microsoft SQL Server Log Shipping Failover" should give you some articles that would be helpful. One of them is called "Fail Over to a Log Shipping Secondary (SQL Server)" and another is "Change Roles Between Primary and Secondary Log Shipping Servers (SQL Server)". These provide detailed steps and considerations when performing the failover.

The very high-level idea is to:
1 - Perform any transaction log backups you can on the Primary database(s)
2 - Apply all available tran log backups (including the one from the step above) to the Secondary database(s)
3 - Make Secondary databases available

Your question of whether to "simply restore the back up again" may have been more geared to how to get Log Shipping started again when you've run into some issue.  If the configuration is correct and you've resolved any outstanding issues, you should be able to restore a recent full database backup on the Secondary in NORECOVERY mode and it will begin applying the log backups from the Primary database again without further intervention. If going this route, it's best to perform a database backup of the Primary using the "WITH COPY_ONLY" clause so you don't introduce complications into your recovery chain. Using that clause tells SQL Server you just want to make a database backup "on the side" that you want to be able to toss away when you're finished.

Hope this helps.